# Date query not inclusive despite parameter being true

Tags: wp-query, date, date-time

I've set up a small test query to get some posts from October 1 to October 10. I published a post today ( October 10 ) and with the date query parameter of `include` set to true, I would have expected this post to show up in the query results. However, it does not.

If I alter the post's publish date to October 1, it does appear in the results. Though if I change `inclusive` to false, it still appears. Basically, `inclusive` doesn't appear to *do* anything.

If `inclusive` isn't the answer, is there another way to ensure that I get all posts from October 1 to October 10 *including* October 1 and October 10?

```
$args = array( 
    'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'after' => '2014-10-01',  
                    'before' => '2014-10-10',
                    'inclusive' => true  
                ),

            )
    );

$posts = get_posts($args);
if( $posts ) { 
    foreach ($posts as $p) {
        echo $p->post_title . ' on ' . $post->post_date . '<Br>';
    } 
} else {
    echo 'no posts';
}
```

**Edited** to add that I just dumped the date query SQL and the the where clause is

> " AND ( ( post_date >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00' AND post_date <=
>   '2014-10-10 00:00:00' ) )"

So it isn't actually inclusive on the full day at all. Filtering the value to

> " AND ( ( post_date >= '2014-10-01 00:00:00' AND post_date <= '2014-10-10 23:59:59' ) )"

actually includes posts made during the day of October 10.

Comment: For anyone getting here in 2022, it looks like [the bug in question](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26653) was fixed in WordPress's core right after OP made this post. `'inclusive' => true` should now work the way that you would expect it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to work with `yyyy-mm-dd` strings, for example `'2014-10-10'`, you could do something like:

```
'before' => '2014-10-10 + 1 day - 1 second',

'before' => '2014-10-10 + 86399 seconds',

'before' => 'tomorrow 2014-10-10 - 1 second',

'before' => '2014-10-10 tomorrow - 1 second',
```

or

> just append `'23:59:59'` to your `yyyy-mm-dd` string

to get

```
'before' => '2014-10-10 23:59:59'
```

Comment: It turns out that you can write `'before' => '2014-10-10 23:59:59` directly as the date query parameter since that is a supported date string. If you'll add that, I will accept this answer.

Comment: yes because the `$before` and `$after` strings are taken through the `strtotime()` function in the `WP_Date_Query()` class.

Comment: The "inclusive" behavior still doesn't seem totally intuitive to me, but I do understand it now, so thanks for the help.

Comment: yes I agree, it turns out that the `inclusive` parameter  only determines  if the date comparisons are using `<` and `>` (false) or `<=` and `>=` (true).